# qpid how to configure receiver

Tags: java, messaging, qpid

I am using Apache Qpid, I take a look at the examples but can't find anywhere how to configure the Receiver in a way that it will not close the connection and will be checking if there are any new messages in the queue.

Comment: Are you using default_container? A MessageHandler? Then the receivers are not closed until you do it. When you have new message, you should receive it with on_message.

Comment: @MertKoksal I have used the sample example, in there they describe `MessageConsumer` with `ConnectionFactory` which is open and after `1000 ms` timeout is closed

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you are using the Qpid JMS client. Its very basic examples, which really just show the various components available in JMS and are not representative applications (as that would depend entirely on what you wanted to do), have a simple reciever that set up to do a synchronous recieve() call with a timeout, such that it waits for that long for a new message (as sent by other bits of the examples), and if none arrives within the timeout takes that to mean things are done and then exits.

If you want to wait for messages you have various options, such as repeatedly calling receive instead of exiting as the example does, calling recieve with a larger timeout to avoid it timeing out so quickly, or even calling recieve with no timeout at all such that it waits as long as needed for the next message before returning. Alternatively you can register an asynchronous MessageListener for the consumer such that the listener will be invoked as and when message arrive for it.

You can consult any JMS tutorial to get more details on these concepts.